# how to serialize objects with specific fields using serializers.serialize in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to serialize django models for only some specific fields. How do I do that. I have a model as below:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

I am using serailizer as:

```
from django.core import serializers

serializers.serialize('json', Person.objects.all(), content_type='application/json')
```

My output is:

```
[
   {
       model: "myapp.Person",
       pk: 1,
       fields: {
           "first_name": "hello",
           "last_name": "world"
       }
   }
]
```

I want to serialize this model only for `first_name` and output must be as below:

```
[
   {
       model: "myapp.Person",
       pk: 1,
       fields: {
           "first_name": "hello"
       }
   }
]
```

Comment: To do what? If you just write `Person.objects.all()`, then you get the desirded queryset, so I do not really understand the problem. Note that `Queryset.values()` does *not* construct a dictionary, but a queryset of dictionaries.

Comment: I do not understand what <QuerySet [<Person: Hello>]>  means?  Hello is a string how to map it to Person object? and even it happened this is not the pattern of list. Question is totally wrong.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I just want to serialize the returned queryset from database using django.core.serializers.Serialize for only specific fields. so if i query my database using .values() i get queryset of dictionaries which raises  'dict' object has no attribute '_meta' but it works fine with queryset returned from .all()

Comment: @dip bazz, if you want to use Django serializers, then ask question about that! Use field argument in serializer if you only want a [subset of fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/serialization/#subset-of-fields).

Comment: okay. Thanks, @Borut for your response.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Person.objects.all()` also has the `first_name` value in it. You can access it via:

```
for p in Person.objects.all():
    p.first_name
```

Please read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/) for more details.

#### Update:

For serialization, try like this:

```
serializers.serialize("json", Person.objects.all(), fields=["first_name", "last_name"])
```