# Is there a way to fetch and serialize only a portion of data on demand/onclick in Django to improve performance?

Tags: django

I want to fetch a portion of the data and display it on demand/onclick when a user requests for it from django and serialize it.

At the moment, I fetch all data to the client which could cause performance issues as the application scales. How can I achieve that using my `get` code snippet below. It would be great if anybody could help me out with what I am trying to solve. Thank you so much in advance.

```
def get(self, request, hashid=None, lang=None):
        try:
            if hashid:
                pk_id = settings.LKC_HASH.decode(hashid)[0]
                disease = Disease.objects.get(pk=pk_id)
                serializer = CategoriesSerializer(disease)
            else:
                diseases = Disease.objects.values('id', 'translations__subcategory', 'translations__name').all()
                serializer = CategoriesSerializer(diseases, many=True)

            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        except Disease.DoesNotExist:
            return Response({'error': 'Disease Does Not Exist!'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

        except Exception as e:
            capture_exception(e)
            return Response({'error': 'There was an error while fetching the diseases!'}, status=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53466607/how-to-serialize-objects-with-specific-fields-using-serializers-serialize-in-dja) help?

Comment: not really, @StanleyUlili

Comment: _Returning portions of data_ is usually called _pagination_. Please search questions about it.

Comment: Alright @IvanStarostin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way. You can exclude large fields via [`defer()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#defer) or specify exactly which fields you want to load utilizing [`only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#only).

This does only work for querysets though! Opposite to `.filter()` the `.get()` method does not return a queryset but the object itself. So you would want to adjust your `CategoriesSerializer` to deal with a queryset.

```py
disease = Disease.objects.filter(pk=pk_id).only("wanted_field1", "wanted_field2")
```

You could also go for the [`.values()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values)method.

```py
disease = Disease.objects.filter(pk=pk_id).values("wanted_field1", "wanted_field2")
```

Those methods pass the specification of the field directly to the SQL commands.

I think once you grab the object itself and you're not dealing with a queryset anymore it always loads all the fields. That's why you most likely want to keep using a queryset.

I am not 100% sure about this, since I only read about it and never used it myself. I appreciate advice.

##### READ:

Read the second "Note" in [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.defer) section. It says that `.defer()` and `.only()` are for advanced use only and offers another approach. Maybe you should go for that one - up to you.

It creates another model that has `managed = False` defined in `Meta` Class. Inside that model you specify the fields that you commonly use.

Hope those resources match your usecase and help you well.

Comment: Thanks @Tarquinius. Let me try your approach

Comment: What just came to my mind: There is a significant distinction between "not fetching all fields from the database" and "not shipping all fields to the user". First thing I replied to. If your goal is just "not shipping all fields to the user" and therefore limit the output of `serializer.data`, this is way easier and can be done inside of your `CategoriesSerializer`. Any comments on that?

Comment: I am angling at not fetching all fields from the database, and only fetching the needed fields at a time. Seems I'll have to do the heavy lifting